# Laravel Microsites Multidomain Multiuser (-type) Authentication possible?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I was wondering if it's possible to develop a Laravel application consisting of three components. These have the following requirements:

## Frontpage *www*.domain.com

Here all the content, SEO and selling will happen..

## Admin Site *my*.domain.com

Admins can register and create & administrate Projects (one project are allowed to even maintain multiple projects). Projects can be "project1" and "project2".

## Project Sites *{project}*.domain.com

These are micro platforms, e.g. a user can register in project1 and in project2 as well. These two accounts have nothing in common, so there wont be a single sign on. But an administrator of project1 CAN login in project1 with his administrator credentials.

## I'm stuck with it..

How would you concept this project? First of all I understood the concept of domain routing. I also understand laravel roles.. But I have no clue how to combine those things to make such a platform possible..

I really hope to get some inspiration and help here! Thanks in advance

Comment: So all three domains will essentially run off the same platform correct? Same database but the account are all unique within that database?

Comment: Very close, yes. The project1,2,3,4... share the same code but different users, content and so on. Admin is able to manage ALL project pages

Comment: Maybe create a table called sites and make an entry for each one except admin. Make middleware that grabs the url, checks it against the sites, grabs the id and sets a session variable for it. Then set the rest of your tables up so they have a site_id column and you can use the session value to pull the correct data. You could also create a folder in the views for each site and also store the folder name in the sites table and save it to the session. So it pulls the correct view or nav or anything else. I would have domain.com/admin, make a grouped routes with auth middleware for access